# Chrome bug with css clip on nested divs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/47ay1304/1/)

I have such html:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

And such css:

```
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  clip: rect(auto auto auto 100px);
  background: green;
}
```

So parent is completely overlapped by child. In FF I can see the parent, but in chrome it's invisible. But if I'm setting, for example, `left:1px` to child, parent instantly appears. How could I avoid this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried making them siblings rather than parent/child:

```css
.sibling1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.sibling2 {
  position: absolute;
width:100px;  
height:100px;
  clip: rect(auto auto auto 100px);
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="sibling1"></div>
<div class="sibling2"></div>
```

Comment: Actually, a good idea. Fits well to my real case. I'm still interested in other ways of solwing this, but this is only academical purpose, so accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be careful about what you actually trying to do here.

You are telling the child to have a position absolute with 0px on all four sides which I think is where the 2 browsers are processing it differently. You are telling the child it needs to be touching on each side without specifying how wide or high it needs to be.

Chrome seems to treat that similar to if you have just given it `width: 100%;
  height: 100%;`. We can see this by inspecting the element and look at the computed styles, it has given the child a height and width of 100px (the parents height and width).

Firefox on the other hand does not. The child does not have a height or width. In other words its not actually taking up any pixels on the screen, hence you can see the parent.

I don't think this is a bug but rather invalid css and your browser trying its best to display it.

When positioning, either specify top or bottom, and left or right, but not all of them. then give the element height and width.

If you let me know what you are trying to achieve I will happily help where I can.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Did you try to set `width:100%` and `height:100%` into my fiddle? [I did](https://jsfiddle.net/47ay1304/3/), and it does not change anything. Problem is not in positioning, but in `clip` and how chrome renders it.

Comment: Again, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah ok, I see what you mean, the clipping of the child is removing the parent also in chrome. This looks like a bug in chrome. Tested in chrome, edge, FF and IE11